# Why does the equality would mean that solutions exist?

Tags: inequality, vectors, systems-of-equations, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I was trying to find real numbers p, q and r that satisfy both:
$p^2 + 4q^2 + 9r^2 = 729$ and $ 8p+8q+3r = 243$

I checked the answer, it said that we need to construct an inequality:
$(8p+8q+3r)^2 <=(p^2 + 4q^2+9r^2)(8^2+4^2+1^2)$. 
The inequality could be derived from scalar product of a and b, by letting $a=\pmatrix{8\\4\\1\\}$ and $b=\pmatrix{p\\2q\\3r}$.

So, if we substitute the values in, and let the equality holds true, for which $a=\lambda b$ we would be able to solve the question. My question is, why do we need to let the equality to hold true. I am very confused.

Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: I think you have a couple of typos. The last term on the left hand side in the second equation is likely $3r$, not $8r$. Also, the top matrix element in $a$ is $8$

Comment: Sorry, is my mistake, I will change it now.

Comment: I think I quite get it, I am so stupid.. I tried to substitute back the values, and both sides of the inequality are the same. So, yes, if we solve this, we could find the values of the two equations

Comment: Should I delete the question, cuz I substitute back, and find the answer...

Answer (score 2):

The answer tells you to use the [Cauchy-Scharz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) inequality. For two vectors, this reduces to $$|a\cdot b|^2\le|a|^2|b|^2$$
The equality occurs only if $a=\lambda b$. In your case, $a\cdot b=243$, $|a|^2=8^2+4^2+1^2=81$, and $|b|^2=p^2+4q^2+9r^2=729$. You can easily check that $243^2=81\cdot 729$. So in this particular case (for the given numbers), you have equality.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the discriminant for the quadratic equation in $p$ is
$$
\sqrt{ - 784r^2 + 3888r - 729}.
$$
This need to be non-negative. Then we have a real solution. This can happen, say, for example with $r=1$ and
$$
p=\frac{94+\sqrt{95}}{4}, q=\frac{47-2\sqrt{95}}{8}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

By your work the equality occurs for
$$(p,2q,3r)||(8,4,1),$$ which gives that there exist $k$, for which
$$(p,q,r)=\left(8k,2k,\frac{k}{3}\right),$$ which gives 
$$64k+16k+k=243$$ or $k=3$ and
$$(p,q,r)=(24,6,1).$$
I like the following way.

By C-S:
$$729=p^2+4q^2+9r^2=\frac{(8^2+4^2+1^2)(p^2+4q^2+9r^2)}{81}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{(8p+8q+3r)^2}{81}=\frac{243^2}{81}=729$$
and the rest is the same.